# How can I split the contents of my table into two tables with an index?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with the schema

```
varchar type,
varchar id,
int date,
varchar(MAX) data
```

And I want to split the data column into its own table and give it a unique index that I would put in my existing table (altered to accept an int instead of varchar(max) for data)

How can I select all of the rows and insert the `data` column into one table, then take the newly created auto_incremented id and insert the rest of the columns into another table with the auto_incremented id as the new 4th column?

Comment: is `data` unique, or can it repeat?

Comment: You can leverage the OUTPUT clause for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: @MarcB    Theoretically it can repeat, but it's not something I'm looking to care about uniqueness for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the table to new temp table with Identity column. from that table, first create your new data table, then again create your second table.

```
declare @OriginalTable (type varchar, id Varcher,date int, data varchar(MAX))
declare @TempTable (Ident int identity(1,1), type varchar, id archer,date int, data varchar(MAX))

insert into @TempTable (type, id, date, data) select * from @ OriginalTable

-- Create the Split tables
select ident, type, id, date into @Table1 From @TempTable
select ident, data into @Table2 From @TempTable
```